# Libreoffice writer cannot export images into a pdf after an update

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

I have a odf document containing various images: jpg and png mostly.

When I export it to pdf, in the resulting pdf file I can't see any picture but only the text.

Any idea why? Oh and I think it stopped working after a general ubuntu 20.04 update that I performed.

The version of the writer in 7.2

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which version of LibreOffice? Please edit to add these information.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi done

Comment: Is it a snap package or the PPA?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi what does that mean?

Comment: How did you install LibreOffice? Ubuntu 20.04 comes with version 6.4.

Comment: It was already installed I guess. Anyway it is version 7.2

Comment: Please post the outputs of `snap list` and `apt-cache policy`

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the LibreOffice snap (I am guessing it is the snap package, because the LibreOffice Fresh PPA is still at version 7.1 as of today, and Ubuntu 20.04 has LibreOffice 6.4 in the repositories). I suggest you to use the LibreOffice PPA instead. It would eventually be updated to version 7.2.

First remove the LibreOffice snap with

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```

You can install version 6.4 with

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

---

If you want the latest version,then install LibreOffice from the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Right now it hosts version 7.1, but it would be updated soon.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice
sudo apt install upgrade
```

Comment: I have tried to inastall 7.1 by adding the ppa but it says I have unmet dependencies and that it won't therefore install libreoffce

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Yes. And it won't work.

Comment: In fact it would gimme that same error even when I tried to install 6.4 right after having removed the 7.2 and before adding the ppa. That might help you understanding the situation better?

Comment: I really can't say anything without knowing how you got 7.2. It is not there in the update channels. Consider reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: I removed ALL ppas and the libreoffice using snap. Now if I go to the ubuntu software  app and look for libreoffice I get the 7.2.0.4. This means that that version comes with my ubuntu or with an upgrade I did. I can't see any other explanation.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice`? Ubuntu software center uses snap, you might see the snap version there.

Comment: Also, edit the question to post the dependency issue.